# What is the best linux distro for virtualbox? preff. small direct download and big package list

Tags: desktop-environment

I'm building a linux DE called MXLDE(Modern X Lightweight Desktop Environment) using a combination based on openbox window manager if all goes according to plan for my os Modern X at modernxblog.wordpress.com

Please tell me what is the best somewhat lightweight linux distro can be installed in virtualbox and has a similar package selection to openSUSE or Ubuntu.

Thank you to all who answer.

-ANON

Answer (score 1):

I would use Debian

- It is pretty lightweight see [here](https://www.linux.com/news/best-lightweight-linux-distros)
- It is an universal operating system and a lot of other distro are based on Debian so whatever you develop on Debian. it will be easier to port on other distro and even other platform (ARM,RISC, and other)
- It can be install without DE or even X sever so you will have no issue developing your own Linux DE
- It has a really good package choice and package manager
- It is well maintained and pretty stable

For all this reasons it would be my choice